# Get first word of a sentence and two characters from second word in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$myvalue = 'Test some more';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[0]; // will print Test
```

I use the code above to echo the first word from a sentence. Now I would like to also echo the first two characters from the second word. So that the above echo would result in:
**Test so**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myvalue = 'Test some more';
$pos = stripos($myvalue, ' ');
echo substr($myvalue, 0, $pos + 3);
```

Comment: You might want to change that "+ 2" to "+ 3"

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $arr[0] . " " . substr($arr[1],0,2);
```

You should probably add a check in to make sure that $arr contains enough words to do this though

```
if(count($arr) >= 2)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line :

```
echo $arr[0] . substr($arr[1],0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a substring?

```
$myvalue = 'Test some more';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[0] . ' ' . substr($arr[1], 0, 2); // will print Test so
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $myvalue = 'Test some more';

    $arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
    echo $arr[0]; // will print Test

    # first two simbols!
    echo ' ' . substr( $arr[1], 0, 2 );
?>
```